# Compatibility between Unreduced Suspension Iso and Reduced Suspension Iso

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I need some clarifications on these two "basic" things because I realised I was using them carelessly and now I want to know once and for all the relation between the two.

Let us assume working with pointed CW-complexes. Let $h \colon SX \to \Sigma X$ an homotopy equivalence between the unreduced and the reduced suspension, which we know it exists.

> The unreduced suspension isomorphism $H^i(X)\to H^{i+1}(SX)$ is provided by the connecting homomorphism of the M-V sequence of the triad $(SX,CX_+,CX_-)$

(or the version with the homology of the pair, which I think provides the same isomorphism - or at least some compatible isomorphism)

> The reduced suspension isomorphism was indicated to me to be the map $H^i(X)\to H^{i+1}(\Sigma X)$ $\sigma \mapsto \sigma \wedge \imath$; where $\imath \in H^1(S^1)$ is a generator. The proof I've seen of this fact uses the Künneth formula for reduced cohomology (Hatcher page 276 for example)

My question is the following: In the past I interchanged the two things carelessly, so I decided to prove if there are some kind of compatibility between the two, by compatibility I mean for example (for $i>0$) that the following diagram commutes

[image]

**Maybe this is not the right diagram or the right notion of compatibility** but this is the point of the question, I'm confident that interchanging the two notions (for well-behaved spaces) shouldn't provide issue, and therefore there should be some kind of compatibility between the two. Clearly I wasn't able to prove commutativity of the diagram above :(

Am I on the right track? For me it is even more important to know if the question as written as this makes sense, because the confusion my rise from a non precise idea-definition of some concepts in my mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it seems I've found what I was looking for.
It is a consequence of the axioms of a multiplicative cohomology theory. The question I've written may seem a little confused, but I think there is a splendid explanation on Tammo tom Dieck's Algebraic Topology at page 413, Proposition 17.3.1

[image]

clearly, $\sigma$ is the suspension isomorphism he defined rigorously a little bit earlier.